# use jsoup to download file, response bodyStream only can get one megabyte file downloaded

Tags: java, jsoup, response, fileinputstream

I use jsoup to download some files form website , by using the code below ,I can get the file download response body

```
 private HttpConnection.Response getResponse3(String url, String resource_url) throws IOException {
    Response resource_download;
    resource_download = Jsoup.connect(resource_url)
            .method(Method.GET).header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36")
            .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
            .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8")
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
            .header("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8")
            .header("Referer", url)
            .cookie("CASTGC", "TGT-1479-kzRU5mnAuwVmsfJFcaHDT1iIrD6V7C1kUvi6IMi")
            .followRedirects(true)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .execute();
    return resource_download;
}
```

then I just return the response objet to another method to get the file download. The method is just looks like this below:

```
        File file = new File(downloadFilePath + fileName);
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = response.bodyStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        fos.close();
```

however , I can only get one megabyte of the file downloaded, which is about 
70M or so . So I wonder why these code can not work properly ? What's wrong with it.

I also read some advices said it's better to use HttpURLConnection to download files instead of jsoup, but the reason why I do it this way is because I think jsoup can carry the cookies and some other infos of the browser to get the file download stream, while if I send another request to the file url I hava to write those infos and cookies again. Without those info I will be detected by the server and they may deny my access.

Comment: Is your file `text`?

Comment: nope, it's a normal file , .rar  or .zip etc files

Answer (score 1):

Use `.maxBodySize(0)` before `.execute()`.
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#maxBodySize-int-

Comment: yeah, I think it's a good idea.. But will it load all the max size of data to the memory of my computer at once ?  What if the file is too big for about 100 to 200 megabytes , is it a big challenge for the memory of my computer ?

Comment: By the way ,I really don't know how big the file is before I get the response. Which is really annoying.

Comment: There are two types of parsers: DOM and SAX. DOM parses whole file at once like Jsoup. It you want to avoid loading big file into memory then you need SAX type of parser. It parses file as it's being read.